# Is it possible to automatically detach from current tmux session when attaching to another one?

Tags: shell, tmux

When attempting to attach to a new tmux from within a tmux session an error is shown:

```
sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force
```

Why sessions shouldn't be nested is understandable but it makes jumping between tmux sessions annoying as you need to detach manually then re-attach to a new session.

Is it possible to create a command which detaches from the current tmux session and attaches onto the given one without resorting to unsetting $TMUX?

I tried `alias tm="tmux detach; tmux new -A -s"` however this doesn't work which isn't surprising as `tmux new -A -s` is run the shell I just detached from not the shell I am returning to.

Comment: why not using `CTRL + b` then `(` `)` to change session ?? For more, https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> detach-client [-aP] [-E shell-command] [-s target-session] [-t target-client]
> ```
>
> […] With `-E`, run `shell-command` to replace the client.

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#detach-client))</sup>

```
tm() { tmux detach -E "tmux new -A -s '$1'"; }
```

You may want to add some logic to cover the case where `$1` is empty.

Comment: Don't do this, use switch-client.

Comment: @NicholasMarriott What is wrong with this approach? The OP used `tmux new -A` so I assumed the target session may or may not exist. With `switch-client` you need additional logic in case the target session doesn't exist.

Comment: It's fine, but switch-client will do less work because the client won't restart. If you want to create the session if it doesn't exist you can do: tmux new -dsfoo; tmux switchc -tfoo. I should really make it so that new-session inside tmux acts like switch-client since that is most likely what the user intends.

Comment: @NicholasMarriott Seems right. I will upvote such answer if it appears.